# Fetching data from command line output using python

Tags: python, mks

Here is the command I used to get the file info, in which am interested in only revision version.
**command:**

```
 command='si revisioninfo D:/Documentation/file_folder/file.c'
 process = Popen(args=command,stdout=PIPE,shell=True)
 file_output=process.communicate()[0]
 print file_output
```

**output:**

```
Sandbox Name: D:/Documentation/project.pj
Revision: 1.7
Labels: Review_1
```

Out of these I want just the revision data to be assigned to the output.

Answer (score 0):

If the revision part is always the second line of the output you could use [splitlines()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines) to split the string by newline:

```
file_output = process.communicate()[0].splitlines()[1]
```

If that is not the case you could always get the first line that starts with `'Revision:'`:

```
file_output = [line for line in process.communicate()[0].splitlines() if line.startswith('Revision:')][0]
```